# GraalVM / Quarkus ; freeze when building native app

Tags: java, redhat, quarkus, graalvm

I try to make a native app with Quarkus, but when I build it, it freeze :

```
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] /home/dorian/graalvm-ce-java8-19.3.1/bin/native-image -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-DCoordinatorEnvironmentBean.transactionStatusManagerEnable=false -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Drx.unsafe-disable=true -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=1 -J-Duser.language=fr -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --initialize-at-build-time= -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -H:+JNI -jar user-service-1.0.0-runner.jar -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:+AddAllCharsets -H:+IncludeAllTimeZones -H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https --enable-all-security-services -H:NativeLinkerOption=-no-pie --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace user-service-1.0.0-runner
[user-service-1.0.0-runner:11835]    classlist:  30 869,22 ms
[user-service-1.0.0-runner:11835]        (cap):   1 077,75 ms
[user-service-1.0.0-runner:11835]        setup:   3 648,84 ms
19:06:13,483 INFO  [org.hib.Version] HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.14.Final
19:06:13,495 WARN  [Hypersistence Optimizer] You should use Hypersistence Optimizer to speed up your Hibernate application!
19:06:13,496 WARN  [Hypersistence Optimizer] For more details, go to https://vladmihalcea.com/hypersistence-optimizer/
19:06:13,496 INFO  [Hypersistence Optimizer] 
 _    _                           _     _
| |  | |                         (_)   | |
| |__| |_   _ _ __   ___ _ __ ___ _ ___| |_ ___ _ __   ___ ___
|  __  | | | | '_ \ / _ \ '__/ __| / __| __/ _ \ '_ \ / __/ _ \
| |  | | |_| | |_) |  __/ |  \__ \ \__ \ ||  __/ | | | (_|  __/
|_|  |_|\__, | .__/ \___|_|  |___/_|___/\__\___|_| |_|\___\___|
         __/ | |
        |___/|_|

           ____        _   _           _
          / __ \      | | (_)         (_)
         | |  | |_ __ | |_ _ _ __ ___  _ _______ _ __
         | |  | | '_ \| __| | '_ ` _ \| |_  / _ \ '__|
         | |__| | |_) | |_| | | | | | | |/ /  __/ |
          \____/| .__/ \__|_|_| |_| |_|_/___\___|_|
                | |
                |_|

19:06:13,497 INFO  [org.hib.ann.com.Version] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
19:06:13,537 INFO  [org.hib.dia.Dialect] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

- The process continue to take RAM, when my RAM and swap is full it throw out of memory error (I have 32Go of RAM DDR4)
- I'm under Manjaro linux and installed graalvm with the github repository.

Comment: Could you give some details on how you build it? Which command? Is-it through docker?

Comment: I followed the guide on quarkus website so I run : ./mvnw package -Pnative.

Comment: I don't think Hypersistence Optimizer was tested on Quarku. Does it work better when removing it?

Comment: I'm trying and give a feedback

Comment: I tried without Hypersistence Optimizer and it doesn't work too...

Comment: Does quarkus support its Hibernate and Hibernate Panache extensions in native mode ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Panache turned out to be the problem. So I tried to remove Panache, and replace it with more plain Hibernate mechanisms, and the build went on from freezing.

Comment: I don't know why but after upgraded the Quarkus version and graalvm version and remove hypersistence optimizer by replacing with a custom naming strategy (easy and simple) the build passed